# Shipping cost is not added when creating invoices programmatically

Tags: magento2

We are creating invoices via code according to the order's status at worldpay payment center. But when we generate invoice, for some orders it is not including shipping_amount and it is showing as total_due amount. But in payment gateway the full order amount is captured and it returns correct amount in the data

Comment: Could you show some of the code regarding this?

Comment: did u find the solution ? im facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Database Values,

Maybe Your Shipping Amount doesn't Stored in Table or

You are not Selecting value From Table where Shipping Value stored,

Do not use shipping_amount from Session, it will destroy Later.